# How to Change width of a dropdown according to the selected country code

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I was creating a dropdown menu in ReactJs to select country code. The dropdown consists of country code and  country name. I want that the dropdown's width should be equal to the country code only.

I have given width: max-content to select element.

Here is the code for the same. I am doing styling using tailwind CSS.

```
<div className="flex gap-6 flex-col mt-4 text-[#2c3345] font-semibold">
          <label htmlFor="phone">
            Phone Number <span className=" text-red-600">*</span>
          </label>
          <div className="flex gap-2 items-center text-[#2c3345] font-semibold">
            <select
              name="dropdown"
              id="dropdown"
              className="w-max-content  py-2"
            >
              {countryCode.map((element, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={element.code}>
                  {element.code} - {element.country}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>

            <input
              type="tel"
              name="phone"
              id="phone"
              required
              onClick={() => selectHandler("phone")}
              className={`bg-transparent outline-none border-b-2 ${
                selectedLink === "phone"
                  ? "border-[#4065fa]"
                  : "border-[#555959]"
              } `}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Current Output :-

[And here is the current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZikO.png)

I want that the width of the dropdown should be equal to the width of country code only.

Desired output:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwMwU.png)

Comment: try using custom width `w-[custom size]` instead of `w-max-content`

Comment: Do you need element.country at all?

Comment: @GeromeTahud If I use w-[customSize] then it will have a fixed width for all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the width of the dropdown according to the selected country code, you can dynamically adjust the width of the select element based on the length of the country code.

```
const countryCode = [
  { code: "+1", country: "United States" },
  { code: "+44", country: "United Kingdom" }
];

function App() {
  const [selectedCode, setSelectedCode] = useState(countryCode[0].code);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedCode(event.target.value);
  };

  const dropdownWidth = selectedCode.length * 18 + "px"; // Adjust the width based on the length of the code

  return (
    <div className="flex gap-6 flex-col mt-4 text-[#2c3345] font-semibold">
      <label htmlFor="phone">
        Phone Number <span className="text-red-600">*</span>
      </label>
      <div className="flex gap-2 items-center text-[#2c3345] font-semibold">
        <select
          name="dropdown"
          id="dropdown"
          className="py-2"
          style={{ width: dropdownWidth }} // Set the width dynamically using inline styles
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={selectedCode}
        >
          {countryCode.map((element, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={element.code}>
              {element.code} - {element.country}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>

        <input
          type="tel"
          name="phone"
          id="phone"
          required
          className="bg-transparent outline-none border-b-2 border-[#555959]"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks Mate ! Just changed the formula to calculate the dropdown width and it worked like a charm!


const dropdownWidth = selectedCode.length + (selectedCode.length <= 3 ? 0.6 : 0) + "rem";

Answer (score 0):

Since the parent element of both the dropdown (`select`) and `input` components has the `flex` class, this means that the 2 children are now flex items.

To make the dropdown take only as much space as needed, you can make the `input` element take up all the available space inside the flex container, which you can achieve by adding the `grow` Tailwind (TW) class (equivalent to `flex-grow: 1;`) in the `input` element.

I would also suggest adding the `shrink-0` TW class (equivalent to `flex-shrink: 0;`) in the `className` field of the `select` element, which will make the dropdown element take as much space as it needs, but will not allow it to shrink more so as to make more room for the `input` element (will not break in a new line in this example).

Ultimately, your structure should resemble something like this:

```js
...

<div className="flex gap-2 items-center text-[#2c3345] font-semibold">
  <select
    name="dropdown"
    id="dropdown"
    className="shrink-0 py-2"
  >
    {countryCode.map((element, index) => (
      <option key={index} value={element.code}>
        {element.code} - {element.country}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>

  <input
    type="tel"
    name="phone"
    id="phone"
    required
    onClick={() => selectHandler("phone")}
    className={`grow bg-transparent outline-none border-b-2 ${
      selectedLink === "phone"
        ? "border-[#4065fa]"
        : "border-[#555959]"
    } `}
  />
</div>

...
```

Links:

- [`grow` TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-grow#dont-grow)
- [`shrink-0` TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-shrink)